# Upload File and Encode it to base64

Tags: java, android, json, base64

i want to convert pdf to base64 here is the code
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please be little more clear on what are the issues you are facing in above code and what you want to achieve ?

Comment: `C:\\user\\Desktop\\dir1\\dir2\\newtest3.pdf` - I don't understand this file path. How can this be valid for an Android device?